# Linear Algebra set spanning

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I am studying linear algebra and am a bit confused by something I've read. I understand this is probably extremely simple maths for the more adept members of the community, but I hope you will still be willing to engage with me on this. 
Really, the crux of the question is:

In a linear system, how can one tell if there is a solution to the system for all values of variables.

This case in particular:

$V = {\mathbb{R}}^{3}$

$S = \big\{\vec{V_{1}}^{\,} = ( 1, 2, 1), \vec{V_{2}}^{\,} = ( 1, 0, 2), \vec{V_{3}}^{\,} = ( 1, 1, 0)\big\}  $  - Is our given set of vectors and we must find out if it is a spanning set of $V$.

We can rearrange this into a system of linear equations

\begin{cases} a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} = a \\ 2a_{1}+a_{3} = b \\ a_{1} +2a_{2} = c \end{cases}

Solving for this linear equation, I get

\begin{cases} a_{1}= (-2a + 2b + c)/3\\ a_{2}= (a-b+c)/3 \\ a_{3}= (4a - b -2 c)/3 \end{cases}

Now following this, I should be able to tell if the system has solutions for all choices of a, b, c.

What basis do I have to be able to conclude if this is true or not? As everything in the problem is one variable or another, I haven't got much of an idea how to proceed.

I understand that when the system has an inconsistent result, like $3 = 5$ then there are no solutions, when, it is a self evident solution like $5=5$, it has infinitely many solutions and when $x = 4$ then there is that one solution, but I'm really uncertain how to apply this knowledge here or if it is even relevant.

I would really appreciate someone taking the time to point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

David

Comment: What you did is correct. You've shown that any vector $(a,b,c)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ (because your system of equations has a unique solution). By definition, this means that $S$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, you've also found a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform row operations to reduce the system of equation to row echelon form and if there is no solution, you are going to get a contradiction like $0=1$.

Otherwise, there is a solution.

For your particular example, when $a, b, c$ is given to you, you can evaluate $a_1, a_2, a_3$, that is a solution to the system.

Comment: So I may assume, that if I can find a straightforward expression for each variable $a_{1}$ etc, in terms of these other non-concrete letters, that there is a solution? In a sense, do I disregard the potential values that $a, b, c$ may take?

Comment: if I change your problem to $v_1=(1,0,0)^T, v_2=(0,1,0)^T$ does it span $R^3$?

Comment: If they're transposes like they seem to be, I think yes? Would it describe something akin to the $xy$ plane? Or am I missing something here? Thank you by the way for taking the time :).

Comment: If we solve the system, we will get expressions like $x_1=a$, $x_2=b$, $0=c$. So we need to ask ourselves, is there a contradiction though we have an expression for $x_1$ and $x_2$. Since it is possible for $c$ to be non-zero, it doesn't span $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, suppose $V= \{ (a,b,0): a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ then $v_1$ and $v_2$ does span $V$.

Comment: I see! Then in essence the expressions of $x_{1}$ should in some form describe the "shape" of $V$ in space, If our original $V$ is given as a 2D object only two of the $x_{n}$ are relevant and thus span the space. I think I understand fully now.
Thank you!!!